# How to query a column with arraylist

Tags: java, sql, caching, ignite

I have a SQL database and one column of that database is a short array.

| Column name | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| Order Id | Integer |
| Timestamp | Long |
| Activity | Short [] |

I want to query this table and get a count of rows that include a given short value in this Activity column. I have tried following SQL statement.

```
private static final String SYMPTOMS_GET_ACTIVITY_TYPE_COUNT =
    "Select count(_val) from PatientTrigger where orderId = ? and  ? = ANY(activity)";
```

But I am getting the following error: `Unsupported expression: ANY(ACTIVITY) [type=Aggregate]`

I am using Apache Ignite caches. Please tell me how to do this correctly.

Comment: `ArrayList` is not a SQL type.  Please clarify what database you are using.

Comment: It's a `Array`. not `ArrayList`. edited the post.

Comment: What database are you using? Please tag your question with the appropriate database tag.

Comment: Database is in an Ignite cache.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that you can't. As noted in the comments, an array isn't a SQL type, at least not in ANSI SQL-99 which is what Ignite supports.

Typically you'd resolve this by normalising your cache and using a join in your SQL. That is, you'd have a one-to-many relationship between your PatientTrigger table and the (new) Activity table.

Comment: Could you please explain this further. its a short [ ].
`Typically you'd resolve this by normalising your cache and using a join in your SQL.`

Comment: If you leave it as a short array, you can't query it using SQL. You need to create a new table, with each entry in your Array as a row. Then you can use a SQL join to query the activity.